# Trouble with Javascript object manipulation

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a JavaScript object that is made up of several key/value pairs of string keys and JavaScript objects.

```
var obList = { key:{..}, key2:{..}, key3:{..}, ... }
```

And I construct a new set, obList2

```
var obList2 = { key:{..}, key2:{..}, key3:{..}, ... }
```

I want to write a function that modifies obList based on obList2. The initial step I'm having trouble with is removing all objects in obList that have a key not present in obList2. Any thoughts/implementation of this would be v helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over objects using a [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and check if properties exist using [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty).

Example:

```
for (var prop in obList) {
    if (obList.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !obList2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        delete obList[prop];
    }
}
```

The first condition is a safeguard against modifications to `Object.prototype` and the second checks to see if the property isn't present on the second object.

Answer (score 0):

Basic element for your code: ability to check if a particular key is missing from an object. Here's how you'd do it:

```
if (window.bla === undefined) { 
  console.log("Key bla is missing!")
}
```

Comment: What if a property is specifically set to `undefined`?

Comment: Great point. Don't know if it's practically applicable, but I did learn something today - I won't be comparing stuff to undefined anymore :-). Thanks, Radu!